# Jasper Reports Server 6.2 does not apply setNumberFormatOverride

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart, jasperserver

I am trying to customize a StackedBar3D chart in Jasper Reports to show ticks in one hour increments for values which are in milliseconds. I achieved this with the following code in JasperServer 6.1 running on windows. My problem is when I try to execute the same report and jar in JasperServer 6.2 running on Centos it applies tick unit but numberformatoverride is ignored showing ticks in millions. Weird thing is I also executed the same report successfully with the same data running with Java (without server) with Jasper Reports 6.2 library.

```
public class TickCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4445304350656126487L;

    public void customize ( JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart )
    {

        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
        NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis) rangeAxis;

        numberAxis.setTickUnit( new NumberTickUnit( 3600000 ) ); 
        numberAxis.setTickLabelsVisible( true );
        numberAxis.setTickMarksVisible( true );

        numberAxis.setNumberFormatOverride( new DecimalFormat()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public StringBuffer format ( double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos )
            {
                return toAppendTo.append( (int) ( number / 3600000 ) );

            }

            @Override
            public StringBuffer format ( long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos )
            {
                return toAppendTo.append( (int) ( number / 3600000 ) );
            }

            @Override
            public Number parse ( String source ) throws ParseException
            {
                return null;
            }

        } );
        plot.setRangeAxis( numberAxis );

    }
```